# Smooth surface that is a complete intersection

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, projective-geometry

I have this definition of a projective complex algebraic surface that is a complete intersection.

A surface $S\subset\mathbb{P}^{r+2}$ is said to be a complete intersection if it is a trasversal intersection of $r$ hypersurfaces $Y_1,\dots,Y_r$ that are smooth at the points of intersections.

My question is: is this surface $S$, defined like this, always smooth?

Comment: Yes: the tangent space to the surface at a point is the intersection of the tangent spaces of the hypersurfaces, and your hypotheses ensure that this intersection has dimension 2 at every point of the surface.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh: I'd recommend making that an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(OK, reposting my comment to remove this question from the unanswered list.)

Yes: the tangent space to the surface at a point is the intersection of the tangent spaces of the hypersurfaces, and your hypotheses ensure that this intersection has dimension 2 at every point of the surface.